# How do you add a horizontal line after a tabset without creating a blank entry in the TOC for RMarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown

I have an RMarkdown file:

```
---
title: "Analysis"
author: "Me"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output:
  html_document:
    toc: true
---

---

## Summary {.tabset .tabset-fade}

### Total {.tabset .tabset-dropdown}

#### h1
plot1

#### h2
plot2

### Approved {.tabset .tabset-dropdown}

#### h1
plot1

#### h2
plot2

### Denied {.tabset .tabset-dropdown}

#### h1
plot1

#### h2
plot2

## {-}

---

## Details

**text**

---
```

This issue I'm having is with this bit of code here:

```
## {-}

---

## Details
```

By adding a blank header, the tabset closes off and the horizontal line renders properly. Without the blank header, the horizontal line doesn't appear at all. The problem is that `## {-}` creates a blank entry in my table of content. Any idea how to make the horizontal line render while not creating a blank entry in the toc? Also, I already tried just `##` without the curly braces and it produced the same error.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Alright I found it: `## {.unlisted .unnumbered}`